# SQL merge Columns from existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL which shows total tickets per month, per location (0900, 0800, 0700 etc) and spans over many years:

```
Select
    Format(Ticket.CheckedInDate, 'yyyy-MM') As 'date',
    CompanyAddresses.CompReferenceId,
    Count(Ticket.TicketID) As TotalAll
From
    Ticket Inner Join
    CompanyAddresses On Ticket.CompanyId = CompanyAddresses.CompanyId
Group By
    Format(Ticket.CheckedInDate, 'yyyy-MM'), CompanyAddresses.CompReferenceId
Order By
CompanyAddresses.CompReferenceId, 'date'
```

and I get the following output (I have limited to one year as an example):

```
2019-01 0900    44
2019-02 0900    44
2019-03 0900    33
2019-04 0900    27
2019-05 0900    37
2019-06 0900    46
2019-07 0900    74
2019-08 0900    43
2019-09 0900    64
2019-10 0900    69
2019-11 0900    54
2019-12 0900    34
2019-01 0800    128
2019-02 0800    91
2019-03 0800    134
2019-04 0800    117
2019-05 0800    109
2019-06 0800    97
2019-07 0800    96
2019-08 0800    115
2019-09 0800    111
2019-10 0800    117
2019-11 0800    97
2019-12 0800    91
2019-01 0700    241
2019-02 0700    183
2019-03 0700    196
2019-04 0700    180
2019-05 0700    180
2019-06 0700    145
2019-07 0700    129
2019-08 0700    149
2019-09 0700    145
2019-10 0700    158
2019-11 0700    120
2019-12 0700    104
```

But I want to show it like this so I can graph it easier.  I have limited to one year as an example but final will span over many years:

```
    2019-01 2019-02 2019-03 2019-04 2019-05 2019-06 2019-07 2019-08 2019-09 2019-10 2019-11 2019-12
0900    44  44  33  27  37  46  74  43  64  69  54  34
0800    128 91  134 117 109 97  96  115 111 117 97  91
0700    241 183 196 180 180 145 129 149 145 158 120 104
```

Your help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use dynamic pivot to pivot all the YearMos.

Please check the example [**here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad5927aed759b368a46ec828cb63d130).

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select ca.CompReferenceId,
       sum(case when month(t.CheckedInDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [2019-01],
       sum(case when month(t.CheckedInDate) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as [2019-02]
from Ticket t Inner Join
     CompanyAddresses ca
     on t.CompanyId = ca.CompanyId
where t.CheckedInDate >= '2019-01-01' and
      t.CheckedInDate < '2020-01-01'
group by ca.CompReferenceId
order by ca.CompReferenceId
```

Comment: The dates span back several years and looking for a way to automatically do this

Comment: @Belliez You only listed one year in your question, so maybe make the requirements a bit more clear.

Comment: ok, understood.  Format(Ticket.CheckedInDate, 'yyyy-MM') As 'date' takes all the dates available and formats it by year/month.  I didn't want to list the entire output here so limited to last year as an example.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is transpose of rows and columns in other words it's called cross tab reports in crystal reports but in sql the easiest way to approach it is through PIVOT tables here is an example of pivot table.

https://www.essentialsql.com/create-cross-tab-query-summarize-data-sql-server/